# Межпроцессное взаимодействие, сколько чего доступно

Tags: c++, процесс

Доброго времени суток!

1) Скажите, как определить максимальный доступный мне объем shared memory, ячейку какого минимального размера я могу создать(1 б?) и сколько отдельных блоков shm я могу создать? Есть ли какие-либо ограничения?

2) Какое максимальное количество процессов я могу создать? Я понимаю, что там тратятся системные ресурсы на обслуживание, можете сказать какие - если что-то имеет фиксированный объем? Что еще и на что конкретно тратится?

Я, конечно, могу позапускать тест-программы, но хотелось бы узнать как оценивать все эти величины/рассчитать/где-то смотреть. Буду сильно благодарен за конкретные числа.

Подразумевается стандартное железо, ноут/пк, использую boost::interprocess, C++.

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы операционную систему упомянули... На стандартном железе можно много чего разного запустить :)

Comment: 1) От одной страницы (4Кб на Intel) до `shmmax`. 2) До `pid_max`. Тратится чуть-чуть памяти ядра на `task_struct` и много на стек/кучу (если они уникальны).

Comment: @Harry Я преимущественно работаю с Win (7), поэтому пока делаю с boost.

Comment: @myaut, я посмотрел на linux, 
   ------ Shared Memory Limits --------
   max number of segments = 4096              // SHMMNI 
   max seg size (kbytes) = 32768               // SHMMAX
   max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608  // SHMALL
   min seg size (bytes) = 1
Вот и все ответы. А что с виндой? Где посмотреть?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671422/shared-memory-in-windows-limits-c

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/